# How to validate Dynamic data in selenium web driver.how will i validate displayed data after iteration results

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How to validate Dynamic data in selenium web driver. I have a text field where i need to enter **To** and **From** dates and data will vary each time, I can get rows and columns details by iterating using xpath but how do i validate that the displayed data is correct or how will i validate displayed data after iteration results .?

Thanks in advance. Waiting for the some help.

Comment: Read data from somewhere, like a database or save some data sets in a local file.

Comment: Thanks, You mean to store the data in XL file and compare the same with the displayed web app data .?? but every time data will differ right.

Comment: Selecting To and From dates using the same values returns each time different values? You should add some response examples and maybe for 2 searches/filterings.

Comment: Kindly reply with the best possible answers.